# Get label names only for those inputs whose checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a fieldset Like Below

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
<fieldset id="fieldstep1" data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Choose Sections:</legend>
    <input name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-1a">Morning</label>
    <input name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" checked  type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-2a">Evening</label>
    <input name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a" checked type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-3a">Night</label>
    <input name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a" checked type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-4a">Snacks</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I need to get all the label names for checked Checkbox.

Rightnow i use this code.This returns all the lable names.

```
$('#fieldstep1').find('label').each(function(){
var a = $(this).text();
alert(a);
});
```

Here is the Js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sGy38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#fieldstep1').find('label').each(function () {
    if ($('#' + $(this).attr('for')).is(':checked')) {
        var a = $(this).text();
        alert(a);
    }
});
```

Explanation: For each label `$('#' + $(this).attr('for'))` gets the checkbox to the label and `.is(':checked')` checks if it is checked.

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGy38/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#fieldstep1 input:checkbox:checked + label').each(function(){
var a = $(this).text();
alert(a);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wh2S7/)

See

- [next adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)
- [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

---

After checking the demo site:

```
$('#fieldstep1 input:checkbox:checked').prev().each(function () {
    var a = $(this).text();
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: for some reason it did not loop through in my main html page ..anyway +1 for ur references :) and raidiri answer is working

Comment: whether your html in the fiddle is the same as the one in your page

Comment: @Vishnu what I'm asking is whether the structure is the same... whether the label is coming after the input element

Comment: @Vishnu where are the check boxes

Comment: @Vishnu the problem is the label is first in the markup then the input element